# Given integers, $s= 2a+3b, t=9a+5b$, if $17\mid s$, prove $17 \mid t$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Eliminate either $a$ or $b$ to get a value of other variable, i.e. $b,a$ respectively with coefficient as $17$. Say, if eliminate $a$, then get: $$17b = 9s - 2t -(i)$$ else get $$17a = 3t-5s -(ii)$$ Now, using the fact that there are three terms; can use the linear combination property that the set of divisors (or Power set of divisors) are the same for all three terms, say for $17b, 9s, 2t$ in (i). 
 So in (i), if $17\mid s$, then $17\mid 2a+3b$. 
 How to take this to conclude that $17\mid t$ also is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another perhaps simpler approach. We have that:

\begin{align}
s = 2a+3b &\implies a = \frac{s-3b}{2} \tag{1}\\
t & = 9a+5b \tag{2}\\
Sub &~(1) (2) \\
t& = 9(\frac{s-3b}{2})+5b \\
2t& = 9s-27b+10b \\
2t& = 9s-17b
\end{align}

Clearly $17$ divides $RHS$ because $17|s$ and $17
|17b$. Hence $17$ must divide $LHS$. And since $2$ and $17$ are primes, $17|t$.

Answer (score 1):

If $17\mid2a+3b$, then $17\mid13\times(2a+3b)$. But this means that $17\mid9a+5b$, since$$13\times2\equiv9\pmod{17}\text{ and }13\times3\equiv5\pmod{17}.$$

Comment: Agree, but if my approach could also lead somewhere, then would learn a lot more about the linear combinations. I do not want to solve it by congruences. Otherwise, please make me realize that my approach is too clumsy to be useless in practice, say if $17\mid s$, then $b\mid 9k$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: I hope my above comment has error as it is not essential for $b=9k$, as only one factor $17$ need divide $s$. So, only $17$ need be a factor of $s$, or $17=s$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $17$ divides $s$, $2t=18a+10b=9(2a+3b)-17b$. Since $17$ divides $2a+3b$, it divides $2t$. This implies that $17$ divides  $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$
3t-5s=17a
$$
Multiply by $6$ to get
$$
18t-30s=6\cdot17a
$$
Add $30s-17t$ to both sides
$$
t=17(6a-t)+30s
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$4s+t=17a+17b$$ and all terms apart from $t$ are known to be divisible by $17$